# char *p[1234567] = { NULL }; segment fault, why?

Tags: c

I'm new to c

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
        char *p[1234567] = { NULL };
        return 1;

}
```

gives `Segmentation fault`

if I change to 12345, it will work.

Comment: There are actually several candidates for duplicates.

Comment: A specific solution here is to move the variable to the static memory area just before main. That area is usually much larger than the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of 1234567 pointers will be more than 4MB.  That is larger than the stack capacity for a thread on many systems. For example, if I recall correctly, on Win32 the address space reserved for a thread's stack defaults to 1MB.

Comment: I inited the array with NULL, it still use memory?

Comment: can you please share any link saying that.

Comment: @roottraveller [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993484/1505939)

Comment: @roottraveller https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Sato, of course, the 1,234,567 pointers containing `NULL` need some storage. Otherwise what do you think, you initialized with `={NULL}`?

Answer (score 2):

Thats most likely because your stack dont have 1234567 * sizeof(char *) bytes of space as needed by variable `p`